# 'angular is not defined' in mocha tests

Tags: angularjs, typescript, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm trying to test a controller function which does a very basic task, some snippets below

I import an enum from a custom module I made

```
import { CurrentUser, Right } from "habenero-identity";
```

In the controller, I then have the following function

```
entercanAddModem = () => {
   this.user.hasRight(Right.AddModem);
};
```

When i try to test this with:

```
 @test
 canAddModemCallsUserHasRight() {
   this.user = { hasRight: sinon.spy() };
    var sut = this.sut();
    sut.canAddModem();
}
```

It tells me Right.AddModem is undefined
When I try to stub the Right Enum with

```
sinon.stub(Right, "AddModem").returns(14);
```

I get the error

```
   `D:\Repos\Complete\node_modules\angular\index.js:2
    module.exports = angular;
                     ^
    source-map-support.js:445
    ReferenceError: angular is not defined`
```

IN the habenero-identity module

i tried the angularcontext module, I tried importing angular, i tried putting it on the global variable...nothing works